# A new question on convergence of a series.... featuring euler's number.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

Investigate the convergence of:

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{n^{2}}{e^{\sqrt{n}}}$

I've chosen to try the ratio test in order to prove this one converges. Considering:

$a_n = \dfrac{n^{2}}{e^{\sqrt{n}}}$

and

$a_n = \dfrac{(n+1)^{2}}{e^{\sqrt{n+1}}}$

We get:

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}}=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)^{2}}{n^{2}}\dfrac{e^{\sqrt{n}}}{e^{\sqrt{n+1}}}$

$< \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{(n+1)^{2}}{n^{2}}\dfrac{e^{\sqrt{n+1}}}{e^{\sqrt{n+1}}}$

$< \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\dfrac{n^{2}+2n+1}{n^{2}}$

$< \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n^{2}}{n^{2}}+\frac{2n}{n^{2}}+\frac{1}{n^{2}}$

Which doesn't really tell me much of anything. Most of the other tests that I know of (i.e. have been given for this particular course) either run into the same problem, or are very hard to algebraically solve without destroying the convergence.

Comment: Can you somehow show that $e^{\sqrt{n}} > C\cdot n^4$ for some finite $C$?

Comment: I know that my original $a_n$ is decreasing for $n>16$.

Comment: Also $e^{\sqrt{n}} << n^{4}$, so I'm not entirely sure what help that would be?

Comment: No, $e^{\sqrt{n}}$ grows way faster than $n^4$. For $n = 10^2$, we have $e^{10} \approx 10^{4.34} < 10^8$, but for $n = 10^4$, $e^{100} \approx 10^{43.4} > 10^16$. If you have $e^{\sqrt{n}} > C\cdot n^4$, you have $a_n < \frac{n^2}{C\cdot n^4} = \frac{1}{C}\frac{1}{n^2}$, and you know the latter converges.

Comment: Ah, fair call. Thanks!